# Highlighting Words in Document Displayed in WebPage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a Rails 3 application that queries a Oracle database that stores documents. My Rails application can store the document id but not any content or other meta-data from the document. I also have to send the document number to another webserver (not controlled by my Rails application) to display the document.

I wonder is there a gem or javascript that I can use to highlight certain words in the documents? For example, let say I want to display the word "people" all the places it appears in the document.  I do not know beforehand that the word appears; however, if it is in the document, I want to highlight the word.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [this plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)? I'm assuming you're using jquery as it is the default in Rails 3.